# Failed conversion from .net core 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: c#, .net

Last week I upgraded my .NET Core Web API from 2.2 to 3.0.

I had a lot of issues with packages and still struggling.

***Case 1:*** What I have right now is that all of my tests are failing:
unit tests, integrations tests, etc.

I'm using:

- Nunit  (3.12.0)
- NUnit3TestAdapter (3.15.1)
- Moq 4.13.0
- Microsoft.NET.Test.sdk (16.2.0)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing

When I start debugging my tests I get the following error message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException HResult=0x80070002
>     Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     Source=System.Private.CoreLib.

The error occurred in the `RuntimeAssembly` file (part of system.private.corelib), method `InternalLoadAssemblyName`.

When I continue I get this:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

***Case 2:*** When I'm not debugging my tests but just run my application en startup swagger, I can use every call but my output window is filled with thousands of Exceptions like thrown:

> 'System.InvalidCastException' in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll

This happens when the Linq class `Where.SpeedOpt.cs` is used and the `List.cs` class of generic, also in `System.Private.CoreLib`.

Are case 1 and case 2 related to each other?

Anyone have a workaround or solution?

Answer (score 4):

Case 1 also fixed:

When using .Net Core 3.0 and automapper
you should add automapper with additional parameter

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

In .Net core 2.2 i just had

```
services.AddAutoMapper();
```

He fails on this during unit and integrationtesting
not on normal startup

Answer (score 1):

Case 2 (swagger error) is solved.
Seems there was a bug in the swagger 5.0.0 packages
That bug is solved in the 5.0.0-rc4 version

Case 1 is still open.
I tried to reproduce with different coding and see what the results are.

When i instantiate a new httpclient, there is no error.
Nevertheless, i can not call my api because it's secured and i get the "unathorized" error (normal behaviour)

When i instantiate a new httpclient with my webapplicationfactory, there is the error.
Is there something that is not initialized from startup when i run my tests
instead of running the core api thru normal startup and calling swagger?
Maybe a problem in startup that is only an issue in unit and integrationtests?

Regards

GSharp